# Composer won't add or even download added libs

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have installed symfony very recently and it recommends me to get something called INTL extension...

I used Composer to install symfony after that I wanted to add that extension so I open composer.json in my folder and added symfony/intl like this

```
"require": {
    "symfony/intl": "2.3.*",
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
},
```

and used Composer update which gives the following

```
******* path # composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file.
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Installing assets using the hard copy option
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Acme\DemoBundle into web/bundles/acmedemo
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodi
```

which means composer didn't download the lib
I removed the Composer.lock file and ran Composer Install 
and also composer require still nothing....

but interesting thing is when I go to an empty folder and used "composer require" it worked and downloaded the INTL !
I think the goal of composer is to add libs I want when I want them so
what's the problem ? Why I can't add new libs ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer said you should install the intl extension (ext-intl), then it means the php extension, not the `symfony/intl` (as it's limited to en only). You should remove the package and install the real extension. On debian based systems (Ubuntu, ...) it's the package `php5-intl`

```
apt-get install php5-intl
```

Comment: it said that ?! where ?

Comment: In your first sentence

Comment: you mean Symfony not composer right ?! , No Symfony recommended symfony/intl

Comment: `symfony/symfony` depends on `symfony/icu`, which depends on `symfony/intl`, so this package should already be installed. And at least `symfony/intl` suggests/recommends to install `ext-intl: to use the component with locales other than "en"`, which means the php extension.